# Reading a file with dates in different formats

Tags: python

I have a file where dates are all sort of different formats
Aug 21, 2021
August 10, 2021, 19:59:59 (UTC-04:00)
2022-08-02T23:59:59UTC

I tried reading with  `datetime.strptime` but it needs string to be in a certain format. Ultimately I want to see if the date is in the past or within 30 days of the future, if I could read with datetime I could use  `datetime.timedelta(days=60)` . Is there a way to do this without fixing the underlying data?

Comment: Third-party package `dateutil` offers "Generic parsing of dates in almost any string format".

Comment: You could use [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). Alternatively, try to parse it with each possible formatstr and use the one that works

Comment: Thanks a ton. I will try dateutil. I am doing possible formastr but its painful.